# Update post meta using save_post hook in multisite

Tags: multisite, save-post, post-meta

I am trying to update a post meta field in a custom post type in Multisite.
i am using the `save_post` hook to do so unsuccessfully.

I don't know if the reason / cause is the multisite? or wrong use of the `save_post` hook, bad timing on the hook or something else...

**the following code is part of the home theme meaning this is the main blog.**

```
add_action('save_post', 'saveselected_termtometa', 10, 3);
function saveselected_termtometa($post_id, $post, $update) {

    $terms      = wp_get_post_terms($post_id, 'rsitecat');
    $term_slug  = $terms[0]->slug;

    update_post_meta($post_id, 'ratemate_rsite_selected_type', $term_slug);
}
```

**Ideas anyone?**

Comment: Exactly which part of this fails? What doesn't work?

Comment: doesnt update the meta field. ;) i tried $response = update_post_meta(... and it returns 1 but doesnt get updated.

Comment: While I am sure you think that quip was clever, it doesn't help. Have you tried to `var_dump()` the several variable to see if they actually are what you expect them to be?

Comment: dump which var? i echoed the $term_slug to verify that it exists (it does).

Comment: How do you determine that the value isn't saved? Are you looking in the database directly?

Comment: i created a custom meta field (i have a lot of those) - as i understand it - in your opinion this should work in mulitisite?

Comment: I can't see why this shouldn't work, but haven't tested it. What you are doing is very basic core functionality.

Comment: i know, i tought it might be different on multisite - in anycase - thank you for your help. Will update this post when i will find a solution.

Comment: did you ever find a solution?  I am having the same problem and have tried many different actions.  It's completely ignoring it.

Comment: i went ahead and did a patch (it was a time sensitive project). i created a custom field and added a function that saves the slug of the first term in that custom field. Post Custom Meta field is much easier to get (for some weird reason) than a term / category - does that makes sense? i hope i explained it right ;)